# Image Pixel Row and Column to coordinate system

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image that varies with intensity. The image is a snapshot of an object migrating through a path. The path was traced, and (x,y) coordinates of that object was recorded.

The intensity of that object varies as it travels along its path, and I want to take the intensity values and relate them to where the object is located on (x,y) coordinates.

I do not have the function that was used originally to map the pixel coordinates to (x,y) when the objects path was originally traced.

I am new to image analysis, how can I can take the bright spots on the image along the objects path and map them to where that object is located in (x,y) coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`cp2tform`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html) to estimate the transformation by supplying a list of image coordinates and the list of already transformed (x,y) coordinates.

```
tform = cp2tform(input_points, base_points, transformtype)
```

You can then apply the transformation to other points using [`tformfwd`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/tformfwd.html):

```
 transformed_points = tformfwd(tform, other_points)
```